# How to map nested object with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

Let's say we have this Entity and the corresponding Dto:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class MyEntityDto
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And this Aggregate and corresponding Dto:

```
public class MyAgg
{
    public string SomeProp {get;set;}
    public MyEntity Entity {get;set;}
}

public class MyAggDto
{
    public string SomeProp {get;set;}
    public AggDataDto Data {get;set;}
    
    public class AggDataDto
    {
        public MyEntityDto Entity {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Here is the mapping profile:

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<MyEntity, MyEntityDto>();
        CreateMap<MyAgg, MyAggDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Data, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => {
                return new MyAggDto.AggDataDto
                {
                    /*
                        Can I inject and use IMapper here to get MyEntityDto from src.Entity ?
                        Should I create the Dto with new MyEntityDto(...) ?
                        Any other approach ?
                    */
                    Entity = ...
                }
            }));
    }
}
```

How can I Map nested object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should create a mapping rule from `MyEntity` to `MyAggDto.AggDataDto`.
2. For the mapping rule from `MyAgg` to `MyAggDto`, map the source's `Entity` member to the destination's `Data` member.

```cs
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<MyEntity, MyEntityDto>();
        
        CreateMap<MyEntity, MyAggDto.AggDataDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Entity, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
        
        CreateMap<MyAgg, MyAggDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Data, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Entity));
    }
}
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sLa0VG)

Comment: Thank you so much for the full answer with running code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A small change which makes sense when AggDataDto has more than one entity, which is my real case:

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<MyEntity, MyEntityDto>();
            
        CreateMap<MyAgg, MyAggDto.AggDataDto>() // Map from MyAgg directly
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Entity, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Entity))
            //.ForMember(dest => dest.Entity2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Entity2));
            
        CreateMap<MyAgg, MyAggDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Data, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
    }
}
```

Comment: Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/moH1uZ